# Projection maps in the product of an object with itself.

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

Suppose $\mathscr{C}$ is a category and $(A \times A,p,q)$ be the product of $A$ with itself, where $p$ and $q$ are the projection morphisms.  My question is: can we always take $p=q$?

If so, is this true even when we take the fibre product of $A \rightarrow X$ with itself?
Is there some similar statement for (co-)limits in general?

Comment: Did you try with an example, say in the category of sets ?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I hadn't thought of that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important when learning category theory to remember that every concept is a generalization of something elementary, and nowhere is this more the case than for products. Projections out of products in abstract categories generalize *coordinate functions* from basic mathematics. Just as you must draw two different coordinate axes on the plane, you must use two different projections out of (almost) any product! A nice exercise would be to classify the choices of $A$ for which this works. They're extremely special.

Comment: I really enjoyed that exercise, and recommend it to the OP: it's good muscle-flexing in terms of taking what you know about sets and turning it into something in a general category.

Comment: If $A$ is such an object, for any object $X$, there cannot be more than one morphism from $X$ to $A$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Jehu314 Yes, precisely. And given any such $A$ in any category, $A\times A$ exists and is simply $A$ itself, with both projections the unique map $A\to A$.

Comment: Thank you very much!